# React map function delivers no result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple array:

```
const plaene = [
{
"bezeichnung":"P1",
"erstelltAm":"18.07.2020"
},
{
"bezeichnung":"P2",
"erstelltAm":"18.07.2020"
 },
{
"bezeichnung":"P3",
"erstelltAm":"18.07.2020"
 }
]
```

So if I want to map over that array, I got no result.
Only when I explicitly specify the position in the map function ( plan[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cURKL.png).bezeichnung ) do I get the values ​​displayed. So why does the following not work?

```
export default function Wochen({pl}) {

return ( <div>
    {
        Object.entries(pl).map(plan =>{
            return(
                <Plaene key={plan} title={plan.bezeichnung}/> 

            );
        })
    }
    </div> )
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try without `Object.entries()` as:

```
{
     pl.map((plan, index) => {
         return(
             <Plaene key={index} title={plan.bezeichnung}/> 
         );
     })
}
```

Above `.map()` has the actual entry in `plan` on every iteration for your array, also `index` can be used as key for your component.

Answer (score 0):

`plan` - is the key. Type `pl[plan]` to access the value